# android MediaPlayer Looping

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play a looping Ogg file, I tried enabling `setLooping(true)` but that had no effect so I tried `onCompletionListener` and that's not working either, could someone clarify what I am doing wrong?

```
musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.overworld);
musicPlayer.setVolume(musicVolume, musicVolume);
// musicPlayer.setLooping(true);

musicPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        musicPlayer.stop();
        musicPlayer.seekTo(0);
        musicPlayer.start();
        Log.d("Sound Manager", "Song Completed");
    }
});
```

Following is my play function,

```
public void playSong(int id) {
    try {
        stopSong();
        musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, id);                                               
        musicPlayer.start(); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Ignored
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's known that MediaPlayer is having problems with ogg files.
You could preferrably switch to another file format.

The other thing is, I would go on trying with setLooping(boolean) as it's most likely using the same scheme and its much more clearly.

Calling seekTo() if the `MediaPlayer` Object is stopped causes the MediaPlayer to be in an invalid state. You can call `pause()` instead but I wouldn't call any of these method, why not just seeking? I would guess if you remove the `musicPlayer.stop()` it will work.

Comment: its a song not a SFX and a Mp3 of the same file is 3mb, whereas in Ogg format it's 600kb

Comment: No change...the Log.d never shows up in LogCat, the Listener isn't even firing?

Comment: The solution was to attach the OnCompletionListener after each call to MediaPlayer.create OR set musicPlayer.setLooping(true); after each call to MediaPlayer.create

Comment: @GideonKain Cool! You couldn't see this from code, I guess. Of course that's the case as MediaPlayer.create creates a completely new instance, how should it know the pre-assigned MediaPlayer instance has setLooping(true). ;)

Comment: Is there a way to change a sound being played without havign to useMediaPlayer.create?, or is that just the way it works?

Comment: setDataSource is the method you want

Answer (score 0):

```
remove ....
    musicPlayer.stop(); 
from
     onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCompletionListener()` is not called if your `MediaPlayer` is set to looping, BUT if you don't have it set to looping, you can always just use a completion listener like so

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    }
    mp.seekTo(0);
}
```

You also shouldn't call `stop()` because that stops playback completely, and it doesn't make sense to seek in a video/song that you are not playing.